# ASP.NET and Javascript not working in Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with javascript code inside my controller. The below code working fine with all the browser(IE,Chrome and Safari) but not in Firefox? It prints the javascript code in the browser. Please help me anyone had the same issue. Thanks in advance.

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.location.href = 'myurl'");
    sb.Append("</script>");

    return JavaScript(sb.ToString());
}
```

If any other way to do this please share with me.

Comment: What's firebug saying is the type of the response (text/javascript, something else...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning Content instead of JavaScript:

```
return Content(sb.ToString());
```

But if you just need to redirect users, then it's better to use redirect:

```
return Redirect("myurl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a Redirect action result to redirect the user to `myurl`?

Get rid of the `StringBuilder` logic and just:

`return RedirectToAction(yourAction);`

if it's an action in the same controller, or:

`return Redirect('myurl');`

if it's an URL outside the controller.